# Bash: Find all jars in all subdirs and show their folder, name and size

Tags: java, bash

I'm quite new to the Bash and would like to ask this:
Is it possible (with a 2-liner ;-) ) to
find all jars in all subdirs and show their folder, name and size?

Just like that:

```
/jars/ | abc.jar | 123456
/ext/  | def.jar | 1234
/ext/  | ghi.jar | 2345
```

So it should be sth. like (Pseudo code)

```
find . -name "*.jar" | while read jar; do echo "$jardir | $jarname | $jarsize";
```

Thanks
Bernhard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could do it with find and `-exec`; something like,

```
find . -name "*.jar" -type f -exec du -m {} \;
```

Which will find all files ending in `.jar` and call `du -m` on each found jar file.

**Edit** based on OP comment below. To get everything separately, you could use something like -

```
for i in `find . -name "*.jar" -type f`; do 
  echo $(du -m $i|awk '{print $1}') $(dirname $i) $(basename $i)
done
```

Comment: Thanks, that's almost it. Can I split a filename like
ext/jars/myjar.jar 
into
ext/jars  |  myjar.jar
?

Comment: @Bernie Edited, something like that should do it.

Comment: Wonderful! That's it.
Just one question about $(dirname $i) and $(basename $i):
I guess, 'dirname' and 'basename' are constants, right?
And they're coming from that 'find' command, is that so?
Sorry, that were two questions ;-)

Comment: dirname and basename are both commands. `man dirname` and `man basename` should explain it.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, this question isn't so much about bash itself as about the command-line tools that are commonly available on systems that provide bash.  You can, in fact, perform the heavy lifting mostly with bash itself, but if you want a two- (or in fact a one-)liner then you should meet the `sed` program.  For example:

```
find . -name '*.jar' -exec ls -l {} \; | sed 's,^\([^ ]\+ \+\)\{4\}\([0-9]\+\) \+.* \([^ ]\+/\)\([^ /]\+\)$,\3 | \4 | \2 ,'
```

Yes, it's incredibly cryptic.  Most of the cryptic part is a regular expression that selects the wanted pieces of a long-form directory listing.  But you wanted short, and concision comes with a price.

Answer (score 1):

There's solution using `find` only:

```
find -type f -name "*.jar" -printf "| %20h | %10f | %10s |\n"
```

Comment: I'm in shock and awe about this solution. It took me a couple of times reading the man pages for 'find', to grasp what you're actually doing. Guess, it would take me a year full-time to deeply understand, what the 'find' command can do.
Great answer!

Comment: Yeah, a great tool. I've been using it many years and there are plenty of features not yet discovered. A year is enough to learn only the basic features.